# Sql-Queries Assignment Info exercise

Tags: sql, database

I have to do this problem but i havent been able to do it. Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong? thanks

For all book types with more than 5 published books, display the earliest publish dates for each book type

Ive got one table

BOOK TABLE:

```
bookcode - book_title - publisher_code - book_type - book_price - publish_date
```

This is what i have so far

```
SELECT book_type, publish_date
FROM book
WHERE top 1 publish_date
GROUP BY book_type and publish_date DESC
HAVING count(*) > 5;
```

Would appreciate if someone could help with this exercise.

Answer (score 1):

The query is much simpler than what you tried - the English description translates into SQL almost word-for-word:

```
SELECT
    book_type
,   MIN(publish_date) -- display the earliest publish dates
FROM book
GROUP BY book_type    -- for each book type
HAVING count(*) > 5   -- For all book types with more than 5 published books
```

You correctly identified the need to use the `HAVING` clause, but you missed the need for a `MIN` aggregate function. Leaving aside for the moment the syntax of your `GROUP BY`, you shouldn't have put `publish_date` there, because this would make all your groups have a single member.